# using context and styling elements in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I'm implementing a dark/light theme functionality in a React Native app, but I have a doubt. I managed to get the themes working , but it was only possible because my styles created by the StyleSheet were positioned inside the component. I know that the variables are not accessible outside the function because it creates it's own context, but, is there another way to get the functionality done instead of doing what I did?

code

```
export function Home({ navigation }) {

    const context = useContext(ThemeContext)
    const { isLightTheme, dark, light } = context
    const actualTheme = isLightTheme ? light : dark

    const uiStyles = StyleSheet.create({
        inputStyles: {
        fontSize: 16,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: 8,
        color: actualTheme.syntax,
        paddingRight: 30,
        backgroundColor: actualTheme.ui,
        height: 65,
        marginBottom: 15
      }
    })

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        background: {
            flex: 1, 
            justifyContent: 'center', 
            alignItems: 'center', 
            backgroundColor: actualTheme.bg
        },

        logoTitle: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            fontFamily: 'Ubuntu_700Bold',  
        },

        img: {
            width: 52,
            height: 52
         },

         texts: {
             flex: 1,
             alignItems: 'flex-start',
             flexDirection: 'row',
             width: '100%',
             paddingHorizontal: 24   
         },

         textsView: {
             flexDirection: 'column',
             height: '100%',
         },

         mainText: {
             fontSize: 42,
             fontFamily: 'Ubuntu_700Bold',
             color: actualTheme.syntax
         },

         descriptionText: {
             fontSize: 14,
             fontFamily: 'Roboto_500Medium',
             color: actualTheme.syntax
         },

         uiContainer: {
             flex: 1,
             justifyContent: 'center',
             width: '100%',
             paddingHorizontal: 24
         },

         findBtn: {
             backgroundColor: 'springgreen',
             alignItems: 'center',
             justifyContent: 'center',
             width: '100%',
             borderRadius: 10,
             height: 65,
         },

         btnText: {
             color: '#fff',
             fontSize: 20
         },
     })


   //The function goes on...
```

Comment: Why position it inside the component ? and if you are using React Native navigation 5 you can extend the theme that it provides

Comment: I'm using Context API. do you think its better to use the react navigation theming?

Comment: Even then you will have to use context api, here you can move the styles to a separate file and import it

Comment: I have the same problem. @GuruparanGiritharan Could you please elaborate? How could he use a theme variable from the context in a style from a separate file? From my understanding, only React components can use a context. A Stylesheet is no React component.

Comment: You can do this and switch dark and light themes https://stackoverflow.com/a/63140072/1435722 and conditionally switch the styles for a component

Comment: That is a neat way to switch between different color schemes. However - correct me if I am wrong - you still cannot use these colors in stylesheets unless they are placed inside the component with the `Context.Consumer`. In my use case that is a problem, because I have more than one background color and I want to select it manually for each View component.

Comment: @stefanS I'm on the same boat, I'm doing multiple themes and would really like to use context values inside StyleSheet.create which are placed outside components on the whole project, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @junaiddarajat Sorry, but I cannot remember. :( It has been too long since I worked on that application.