# Create a Theme Provider component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My application needs a color themes providing and I am trying to implement a Theme Providing component using a React Context, but it does not work. I can't figure out how to get the `theme` prop object from the Theme Provider's Context and how can I call the `updateTheme` function that is state of Theme Provider? This is my code:

**ThemeProvider**

```
import React from "react";
import { LightTheme, DarkTheme } from '../themes'

const Context = React.createContext();

export class ThemeProvider extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    theme: LightTheme,
    updateTheme: (theme) => {
      this.setState({ theme: theme })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { theme } = this.state
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state} theme={theme} >
        { this.props.children }
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default ThemeProvider;
```

**App**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { HomeScreen } from './screens';
import { NavBar, ThemeProvider } from './components';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <NavBar />
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Navbar** (this component have to get the `theme` prop from the ThemeProvider to change it's color)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Title } from 'native-base';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { Layout } from '../constants';

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  
  static contextType = ThemeProvider;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Header>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon name='add' size={Layout.navIconSize} />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>Header</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon name='alarm' size={Layout.navIconSize} />
          </Button>
        </Right>
      </Header>
    )
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

**Themes**

```
export const LightTheme = {
   dark: false,
   colors: {
      primary: 'rgb(255, 45, 85)',
      background: 'rgb(242, 242, 242)',
      card: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
      text: 'rgb(28, 28, 30)',
      border: 'rgb(199, 199, 204)',
      notification: 'rgb(255, 69, 58)',
   }
}

export const DarkTheme = {
   dark: true,
   colors: {
      primary: 'rgb(255, 45, 85)',
      background: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
      card: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
      text: 'rgb(28, 28, 30)',
      border: 'rgb(199, 199, 204)',
      notification: 'rgb(255, 69, 58)',
   },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done the major part, you just have to do some minor changes to get it to work.

First
In order to change the values of a context you will have to export the context. Then access the consumer.

```
import React from "react";
import { LightTheme, DarkTheme } from '../themes'

export const Context = React.createContext();

export class ThemeProvider extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    theme: LightTheme,
    updateTheme: (theme) => {
      this.setState({ theme: theme })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { theme } = this.state
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state} theme={theme} >
        { this.props.children }
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default ThemeProvider;
```

In the child component which is the NavBar in your case, you will have to import it and use the consumer to do updates
Import the context like below (Your actual paths may vary)

```
import ThemeProvider, { Context } from './ThemeProvider';


class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Consumer>
        {({ theme, updateTheme }) => (
          <Header>
            <Left>
              <Button
                title="Update Theme"
                onPress={() => updateTheme(theme.dark ? LightTheme : DarkTheme)}
              />
              <Button transparent>
                <Icon name="add" size={Layout.navIconSize} />
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title>Header</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <Button transparent>
                <Icon name="alarm" size={Layout.navIconSize} />
              </Button>
            </Right>
          </Header>
        )}
      </Context.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

**{({ theme, updateTheme }) => (**
The above line provides access to your theme value in the context and updateTheme.
You can try out the code.

Comment: I've tried your code and got error that `theme` value in NavBar component is undefined. I don't understand what wrong

Comment: @anDev can you try this button

Comment: class Btn extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Consumer>
        {({ theme, updateTheme }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(theme)}</Text>
            <Button
              title="Test"
              onPress={() => updateTheme(theme.dark ? LightTheme : DarkTheme)}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </Context.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

Comment: Got the same error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref.theme')`

Comment: Your export is correct right import { NavBar, ThemeProvider } from './components'; you do a default export but import like this

Comment: I used the import statement like in your code, but nothing changed

Comment: can you try this snack https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/-themeprovider

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake. I forgot to wrap `NavigationContainer` with `ThemeProvider`. Your snack helped me, thanks!